# Checks of whether a date is between two dates shows correct for the last year

Tags: javascript

I use the below script to check if a date falls in this month but my problem is that it flags 'current_month' even for dates like '08/01/2017'.

```
var date = new Date();
var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

var fd = date2str(firstDay, "MM/dd/YYYY")
var ld = date2str(lastDay, "MM/dd/YYYY")
var check = date2str(registration_date, "MM/dd/YYYY")

var flag;
if(check <= ld && check >= fd)
flag = 'current_month';
else (flag = 'not_current_month')
```

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57506803/edit) then `[<>]` and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are comparing for example

08/05/2017 with 08/03/2019

where 08/05... is indeed greater than 08/03...

You need to compare using yyyy/mm/..

Like this:

```js
function sameMonth(str) {
  var d = new Date();
  var compareMonth = d.getFullYear()+d.getMonth();
  d = new Date(str);
  return compareMonth === d.getFullYear()+d.getMonth();
}

console.log(sameMonth("8/3/2019")); // this will return true in August 2019

console.log(sameMonth("8/3/2018"))
```

Comment: Thank you, @mplungjan. Can you, please, point out what was wrong with my code?

Comment: No. Your code is not complete. As I asked, create a [mcve] and perhaps I can take a look. What is date2str?

Comment: I found that in order to compare dates, I need to convert them to the MM/dd/YYYY format, which I am achieving with date2str

Comment: Changed my str2date to 'yyyy/MM/dd' and it worked just fine! Thank you!